# How to get value from onchange?

Tags: javascript, date, onchange

Hi I basically am trying to disable another input field if the day is set to today from another input field (date). I can't seem to force an onchange onto an input field and grab that value into a variable to make this work.

I've had success placing the onchange(this) onto the input field but I have to take it out and force a JS onchange onto it instead.

I've tried the following code. As you can see, it is supposed to do something when the time is past 10am and the date is selected as today:

```
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    var hrs = date.getHours();

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    }

    date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;


    var userDateEntry = document.getElementById("fm_deliverydate").onchange().value;

    if (hrs >= 10 && userDateEntry == date) {
        alert("Shipping for today has ended. Your order will arrive tomorrow");
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled= true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled= false;
    }
</script>

<input  type="date" name="DateName" id="fm_deliverydate" />

<input  type="time" name="TimeName" id="fm_deliverytime" />
```

Comment: Where are you adding the `change` listener? Where is `dateEntered` getting called? As written, this code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing the relationship between `dateEntered()` and your inputs elements.  How are you registering the `onchange` handler?  We're missing some key elements to your code.

Comment: I had originally had the method dateEntered() in the input onchange, which I took out. I forgot about dealing with this function in the script!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't attaching the event correctly. You attach an event using `addEventListener`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/125jnvwp/1/

```
var date = new Date();
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
var hrs = date.getHours();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

date = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

var userDateEntry = document.getElementById("fm_deliverydate");
userDateEntry.addEventListener('change',
    function () {
        if (hrs >= 10 && userDateEntry.value == date) {
            alert("Shipping for today has ended. Your order will arrive tomorrow");
            document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled = false;
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to add the onclick event listener to the html then you really only need to remove the onchange method you have attached in your dateEntered function and move it to the html, nothing else changes then.

```
var date = new Date();
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
var hrs = date.getHours();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
}
date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

function dateEntered(){
    var userDateEntry = document.getElementById("fm_deliverydate").value;

    if (hrs >= 10 && userDateEntry == date) {
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled = true;
    } else {
        console.log('shipping enabled');
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled = false;
    };
}
```

Your html would look like this:

```
<input  onchange="dateEntered()" type="date" name="DateName" id="fm_deliverydate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>

<input  type="time" name="TimeName" id="fm_deliverytime" placeholder="enter date"/>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o73fze9r/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the event listener to the element instead, and firing your function when it changes. Try it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dtg33wc/). You could also consider adding a case where the date entered is lower than the current date. As of now you can enter a date in the past and still be able to enter a time.

```
<input  type="date" name="DateName" id="fm_deliverydate" />
<input  type="time" name="TimeName" id="fm_deliverytime" />

<script>
var date = new Date();
var dd = date.getDate();
var mm = date.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
var hrs = date.getHours();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
}

date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

(function(){
    document.getElementById("fm_deliverydate").onchange =  function() {
       dateEntered();
    }
})();

function dateEntered(){
    var userDateEntry = document.getElementById("fm_deliverydate").value;

    if (hrs >= 10 && userDateEntry == date) {
        alert("Shipping for today has ended. Your order will arrive tomorrow");
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled= true;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('fm_deliverytime').disabled= false;
    }
}
</script>
```